# Keyboard flashes between keyboard types when input receives focus

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I am having an issue where the soft keyboard flickers between types when a text field receives focus.

I have a `TextField` where I want to input digits, however the Soft Keyboard flicks between a standard text Keyboard and a number Keyboard when the `View` receives focus.

I have created a quick gif to demonstrate:

[image: gif-demo]

I suspect I am doing something wrong when recompositions are happening, but I can't see where could be causing this.

Below is the code demonstrating the implementation:

```
@Composable
fun PinInput(focusManager: FocusManager) {
    Card(
        modifier = Modifier.size(60.dp, 80.dp),
        elevation = 0.dp,
        backgroundColor = ColorSurface,
        border = BorderStroke(2.dp, ColorLightBorder)
    ) {
        EditableInput(
            textStyle = Typography.h1.copy(
                textAlign = TextAlign.Center,
                fontSize = Dimens.TextSizeGiant
            ),
            onTextChange = { value ->
                if (value.isNotEmpty()) focusManager.moveFocus(Right)
                else focusManager.moveFocus(Left)
            },
            maxLength = 1,
            keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions(
                keyboardType = KeyboardType.NumberPassword,
                imeAction = ImeAction.Next
            ),
            keyboardActions = KeyboardActions(onNext = { focusManager.moveFocus(Right) })
        )
    }
}
```

```
@Composable
fun EditableInput(
    state: EditableInputState = rememberEditableInputState(),
    textStyle: TextStyle = Typography.body1.copy(textAlign = TextAlign.End),
    onTextChange: (String) -> Unit = {},
    keyboardOptions: KeyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions.Default,
    keyboardActions: KeyboardActions = KeyboardActions(),
    maxLength: Int = NO_VALUE
) {
    TextField(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
        colors = TextFieldDefaults.textFieldColors(
            textColor = ColorOnSurface,
            backgroundColor = ColorSurface,
            focusedIndicatorColor = Color.Transparent,
            unfocusedIndicatorColor = Color.Transparent,
            disabledIndicatorColor = Color.Transparent
        ),
        textStyle = textStyle,
        singleLine = true,
        value = state.text,
        onValueChange = { value ->
            if (maxLength == NO_VALUE || (maxLength != NO_VALUE && value.length <= maxLength)) {
                state.text = value
                onTextChange(value)
            }
        },
        placeholder = { Text(text = state.hint) },
        keyboardOptions = keyboardOptions,
        keyboardActions = keyboardActions
    )
}
```

```
@Composable
fun rememberEditableInputState(hint: String = ""): EditableInputState =
    rememberSaveable(hint, saver = EditableInputState.SAVER) { EditableInputState(hint, hint) }

class EditableInputState(val hint: String, initialText: String) {
    var text by mutableStateOf(initialText)
    val isHint: Boolean
        get() = text == hint

    companion object {
        val SAVER: Saver<EditableInputState, *> = listSaver(
            save = { listOf(it.hint, it.text) },
            restore = { EditableInputState(it[0], it[1]) }
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: It's [a known issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/187746439), be sure to star it to get more attention.